# Sessions <> Scans: fetch all scans NOT yet performed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complex domain structure:

```
User:        id, name, email
Team:        id, name
UserTeam:    id, user_id, team_id
Session:     id, data
UserSession: id, user_id, session_id
TeamSession: id, team_id, session_id
Scan:        id, user_id, session_id, test_data
```

I can invite users to take a "session". A user can take a session (one `UserSession` is made) and if completed, the result is stored in a `Scan`. I can also invite a complete team, so one `TeamSession` is created and for every team member, a `UserSession` is made.

Now I want to perform the query: give me all the scans not yet performed (so I can remember users to take one). For this case, I want to select **all usersessions** and join **scans** where the scan id is `NULL`. I thought this was the way to find out a row from a joining table is not present yet.

This was my query:

```
SELECT us.id as userSessionId,
       sc.id as scanId,
       s.id as sessionId,
       u.id, u.name

FROM usersessions us
     LEFT JOIN sessions s ON us.session_id = s.id
     LEFT JOIN scans sc   ON us.session_id = sc.session_id
     LEFT JOIN users u    ON us.user_id = u.id

WHERE sc.id IS NULL

GROUP BY us.id
```

However, it does not work: nothing is returned while at least one user has not performed a scan yet. If I remove the `WHERE` clause to see what the data is, I get this back:

```
userSessionId  scanId  sessionId  id  name
45             45      39         39  John
46             45      39         40  Jane
47             45      39         41  Tom
48             45      39         42  Mark
```

In this case, all are in the same group and got a session (#39). Their user ids and user session ids are correct. Mark has not performed a scan. John did scan #45 (for Jane it was #46 and Tom #47).

If I add a where clause `WHERE sc.user_id=u.id`, I get the correct three results (scans #45, #46 and #47) but then Mark is missing. That's the only one I want to grab in the end! If you change it then to both clauses `WHERE sc.user_id=u.id AND sc.id IS NULL` it (obviously now) returns nothing again.

What's the query to get all user sessions NOT connected to a scan?

Comment: So I'm assuming the `id` field in the `scans` table is not auto-incrementing (can be repeating) and that the columns are unique across the combination of `id -> user_id -> session_id` correct? And can there be multiple scans per session?

Comment: The scan ids are auto incremental, there are *only* multiple scans per session if there are multiple users per session. A session with one user has one userSession and one Scan.

Comment: Okay, and a usersession can exist but without a corresponding `scan` and you want the usersessions that don't have corresponding scans (incomplete) - along with the scanid that didn't correspond, correct?

Comment: @ZaneBien the first part is correct. I want to find all userSessions that do not have a scan connected yet. So there is a UserSession (say, id = 23). And in the Scan table there is NO row with UserSession = 23. In my table above I would expect to have for the last row a ScanId = NULL.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is your desired output? Do you want to select all usersessions, and display `NULL` in the `scanId` field if they don't have a corresponding scan? Or do you ONLY want the usersessions that don't have a scan? What are the columns you want to select?  If you only need the usersession data that doesn't have a scan, you can just use the subselect in the `FROM` clause in my solution alone and it should give you the right results.

Comment: I want to invite the users which do not have performed a scan yet. This involves a username (and id) and session id. Those are the two parameters I am interested in. The null for scan ID is a thought of mine to check whether there is no scan performed yet. But that's not a criteria for the query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13879/discussion-between-zane-bien-and-jurian-sluiman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution. If it works for you, I will edit my post to add an explanation:

```
SELECT
    a.id AS userSessionId,
    b.id AS scanId,
    a.session_id AS sessionId,
    a.user_id,
    c.name
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*
    FROM usersessions a
    LEFT JOIN scans b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.session_id = b.session_id
    WHERE b.id IS NULL
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, session_id
    FROM scans
    GROUP BY id, session_id
) b ON a.session_id = b.session_id
INNER JOIN
    users c ON a.user_id = c.id
```

---

I'm assuming your data looks something like this:

```
usersessions:
id  |  uid  |  session_id
-------------------------
45  |   39  |   39
46  |   40  |   39
47  |   41  |   39
48  |   42  |   39


scans:
id  |  uid  |  session_id
-------------------------
45  |  39   |  39
45  |  40   |  39
45  |  41   |  39
```

In which case you should end up with:

```
userSessionId  |  scanId  |  sessionId  |  user_id  |  name
-----------------------------------------------------------
48             |  45      |  39         |  42       |  Mark
```

Let me know if your scans table is allowed to look something like:

```
scans:
id  |  uid  |  session_id
-------------------------
45  |  39   |  39
45  |  40   |  39
45  |  41   |  39
46  |  39   |  39
46  |  40   |  39
46  |  41   |  39
46  |  42   |  39
```

^ In which case my query would not work, and would need to be rewritten (and I know how).

Comment: This ALMOST works! The only modification is there is one scan PER user. So your first assumption is correct, except for the scan id which is also auto incremented, like user sessions. However, I get now only rows back with Mark's name, so I group by user session id and as far as I can see now, this works.

Comment: @JurianSluiman, just take the subselect that's in the `FROM` clause, and simply use that alone. It should give you one row per usersession so you won't have to use `GROUP BY` to make rows distinct. I was under the impression that you also wanted the `scanid` which they were missing. And of course, if you also need the name of the user, just add a join the the `users` table.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the `GROUP BY` clause in your query.  It is not valid without an Aggregate function but, in MySQL, it doesn't throw an error and will return "random" rows.  Use `ORDER BY` to sort the answer.

```
SELECT us.id as userSessionId,
       sc.id as scanId,
       s.id as sessionId,
       u.id, u.name

FROM usersessions us
     LEFT JOIN sessions s ON us.session_id = s.id
     LEFT JOIN users u    ON us.user_id = u.id

WHERE us.session_id IS NULL

ORDER BY us.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this also returns null. If I remove the WHERE clause to see all results, it looks like this: http://juriansluiman.nl/caps/96411e.png. I am really getting lost here, as I seriously do not expect this kind of results...

Comment: @JurianSluiman  It seems to me looking at your results that it should return NULL since all of your usersessions records have a valid scan_id.  You might try checking if `us.session_id IS NULL` and eliminate the `LEFT JOIN`  (I will update my Answer).

Comment: @JurianSluiman, your data structure needs some normalization.  It may not be possible to get what you need with the current structure.  Consider adding `scan_id` to `UserSession` and removing `user_id, session_id` from the `Scan` table.  (I am assuming a scan cannot exist without a user session.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The Scan is connected to a Session (session_id) and user (user_id). The UserSession is only connected to a session_id. The Scan was set up such because of some heavy queries where I gained benefits to directly connect it to a user and session, instead of using a connection to UserSession and fetch the user and session from there. Perhaps I need to modify my domain models indeed.